# PHP mailer not working on cpanel

Tags: php, email, localhost, phpmailer, cpanel

my php mailer is working fine on localhost but when I m running same code on cpanel I m getting Error message :SMTP connect() failed

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                     
$mail->Host = "tls://smtp.gmail.com"; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = '********@gmail.com';                 
$mail->Password = '********';                           

$mail->Port = 587;                                   

$mail->setFrom('sender@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->AddAddress('receiver@gmail.com', 'Joe User');    
$mail->addReplyTo('sender@gmail.com', 'Information');

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

Pls help me, where I am getting wrong?

Comment: If you comment out the call to `addAddress`, the message is not addressed to anyone, so why would you expect it to work?! You could try [reading the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) that are linked from the error message you're getting.

Comment: but while uncommenting that $mail->AddAddress() it's giving an error:SMTP connect() failed

Comment: You can't even attempt to send if you don't set a recipient, it's not that setting one causes the connection error!

Comment: Are you verified that your Cpanel machine has open port 587 for OUT ?
"SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host."
This may also appear as SMTP connect() failed or Called Mail() without being connected in debug output. This is often reported as a PHPMailer problem, but it's almost always down to local DNS failure, firewall blocking or other issue on your local network. It means that PHPMailer is unable to contact the SMTP server you have specified in the Host property, but doesn't say exactly why. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Answer (score 4):

CPanel blocks access to external SMTP servers by default.

Disable this restriction in whm > security center > SMTP Restrictions disable

This works

```
<?php
require_once('./class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages                         only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "xxxxxx@ymail.com";
$mail->Password = "xxxxxx";
$mail->SetFrom("xxxxx@ymail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("xxxxx@ymail.com");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have forgotten to enable SMTP access (it's part of IMAP access in settings) to your GMail account.

Also, "tls://smtp.gmail.com" is not a valid SMTP server address. Use `$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";` if you want to use TLS.

Comment: @DestylioHarsha Okay, that's a start. See my updated answer.

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps show $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions, It's really appreciated :-)

I got the solution is as follows.

```
1>give Absolute path for PHPMailerAutoload.php
2>host name as "localhost"
3>create dummy emailId on server



<?php
require'/home/username/public_html/phpmailertesting/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug =3;                               // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'localhost';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'info@hostname.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '*****';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
$mail->setFrom('info@hostname.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('*******@gmail.com');               // Name is optional
 //$mail->addReplyTo('info@hostname.com', 'Information');
 //$mail->addCC('*******@gmail.com');
 //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit();
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

Comment: I just started this past week having my emails NOT get generated. This does not mean they are failing, necessarily. They appear to be going through, as they get to the send block where it's successful. I just added a debugging statement on it and it still went through. I have JustHost as the provider. Any ideas what else this could be? While I've used port 587 I have not declared either SSL or TLS in the script. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to buy Cpanel/WHM from the ISP company to enable access to external SMTP emails like Gmail. first, disable: **WHM > security center > SMTP Restrictions is Disable.**
and make sure CSF Firewall is "SMTP_BLOCK" setting is enabled.
if you using Gmail in your security setting enable less security which you can smtp auth.
PHPMailer recommended using SSL for all firewalls and security issues.